# R: dcast descending order

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I've a data frame of the form:

```
time1 <- rep(seq(1,3),3)
time2 <- c(rep(1,3),rep(2,3), rep(3,3))
value <- seq(1:9)
foo <- data.frame(time1,time2,value)

      time1   time2   value
    1     1     1     1
    2     1     2     2
    3     1     3     3
    4     2     1     4
    5     2     2     5
    6     2     3     6
    7     3     1     7
    8     3     2     8
    9     3     3     9
```

I want to use dcast to get a data frame of the following form:

```
time2    1   2    3 (values of time1)
3        3   6    9 
2        2   5    8
1        1   4    7
```

My first try was:

```
dcast(foo, time2 ~ time1,  value.var = "value")
```

but the data frame isnt of descending order of time2. So, I tried

```
dcast(foo, reorder(time2, rev(time2) ~ time1,  value.var = "value")
```

but now the column names are wrong. Is there an efficient way to get my output form with dcast ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `factor()` to convert `time2` into an ordered factor and set the order using the `levels` argument.

```
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)
foo %>%
  mutate(time2 = factor(time2, levels = rev(unique(time2)))) %>%
  dcast(time2 ~ time1, value.var = 'value')
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Is there a way doing it without dplyr ?

Comment: @Leo69 Use `foo$time2 <- factor(time2, ....` instead of mutate. The rest is base R or `reshape2` (except the `%>%`, but those just put the thing on the left as the first argument to the thing on the right)

Comment: Thanks to both of you guys. Helped a lot